# What is the difference 言う vs 言わせたい?

Tags: grammar, translation

I was looking up a lyrics for a song that has the lyrics

```
君の背中追いかけてた
眩しいとか悔しいとか
言うより言わせたい
```

I think the first sentence can be translated to "I chased after your back", second one "Whether it’s too dazzling or it’s regrettable" the third one is the one that I kind of do not understand. "言う" as I understand it is to say. "より" is more than and I know たい refers to a strong desire/want. Hence, the third sentence is " I want to say out more than what I want to say out?" which sounds wrong. What is the difference between 言う vs 言わせたい?

P.S. Just started learning basic Japanese only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome do Japanese Stack Exchange! First, you are correct about 言う, より and ～たい meanings, but you are missing the [causative](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B-saseru-causative-form-meaning/) form ～させる
言う : to say
～せる : make someone do "～" / allow someone do "～"
～たい : want to "～"

Thus:
言わせる : make someone say / allow someone say
言わせたい : want to make say

So I would translate:

> 言うより言わせたい

as:
*More importantly than saying, I want to make you say.*
or
*I want to make you say it instead of saying it myself*

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about the causative form. Although the lyrics is still puzzling to me, but at least this clears up some misunderstanding I had.